# Processing data from file in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file as follows

```
  (-0.548,15.994)
  (1.008,8.91)
  (-0.19,4.594)
  (-0.99,9.99)
```

I used

```
 $ awk '{ mul = $1*$2; print mul }' input.txt > output.txt
```

But all the values of output.txt file are 0s.
Can any one tell me where I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shellter beat me be a few seconds with a better alternative, but here goes:

```
sed 's/[^0-9,\.-]*//g' input.txt | awk '{split($1,x,","); mul=x[1]*x[2]; print mul}' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print the values of $1 and $2 you'll see the problem. You also need to tell `awk` to use `,` as a field seperator.

Here's a revised version of your code.

```
  awk -F, '{ gsub(/[()]/, "", $0); mul = $1*$2; print mul }' input.txt > output.txt
```

**output**

```
-8.76471
8.98128
-0.87286
-9.8901
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can also have several separators, you just have to set field sep `FS` or `-F` wisely, thats enough, you can simplify you command like below

**Input**

```
$ cat f
 (-0.548,15.994)
  (1.008,8.91)
  (-0.19,4.594)
  (-0.99,9.99)
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[(,)]' '{ print $2*$3 }' f
-8.76471
8.98128
-0.87286
-9.8901
```